# Override Message-ID by configuration

Tags: jakarta-mail, wildfly

When I send email from my application using the default WildFly mail session, the auto-generated message ID gives away that my server is WildFly:

```
Message-ID: <524672585.11.1429091886393.JavaMail.wildfly@myserver.example.com>
```

For security reasons, I'd like to suppress or override the `wildfly` substring in the message ID.

Is there a configuration element or a system property to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: The `wildfly` part of the message ID corresponds to the value of the `user.name` system property. My server happens to be running under a Linux user account named `wildfly`.

So one option would be to use a different user account. Alternatively, simply passing `-Duser.name=foo` to the WildFly start script is enough to change the message ID.

Comment: You can also subclass MimeMessage and override the [updateMessageID](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#updateMessageID()) method.

Comment: See also: [Bug 6496 -Message-Id leaks current user/hostname of the Java process](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6496).

Comment: @BillShannon: Yes, I'm aware of that, but i was hoping to avoid changing my code, that's why I asked about _configuration_.

Comment: @jmehrens: Thanks for the pointer - the bug is marked as resolved for javax.mail 1.5.3, but unfortunately there is no release with that version, at least not on Maven Central.

Comment: Check the website again. 1.5.3 was just released.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to [JavaMail 1.5.3](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).  That official release has [Bug 6496 -Message-Id leaks current user/hostname of the Java process](https://kenai.com/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=6496) marked as resolved.

Otherwise, the Message-ID computation uses the [InternetAddress.getLocalAddress](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#getLocalAddress(javax.mail.Session)) method which is including the username.  You can set the [mail.from](http://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) session property to override including the O/S user name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.from", "------@bar.baz");
        Session s = Session.getInstance(props);
        MimeMessage m = new MimeMessage(s);
        m.addFrom(InternetAddress.parse("foo@bar.baz"));
        m.setText("");
        m.saveChanges();
        m.writeTo(System.out);
}
```

Which will output something like:

```
From: foo@bar.baz
Message-ID: <1688376486.0.1429814480627.JavaMail.------@bar.baz>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

If you are using the default session you can just add 'mail.from' to the system properties.

Comment: That does not answer the question. The answer appears to be no. And you can't trivially upgrade a container-level library. However, this upgrade will be included in WildFly 9.0.0.CR1 (see [WFLY-4536](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4536)).

Comment: Edited the answer.  I think the 'mail.from' property does what you need.