# Overriding java internals methods

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, jakarta-mail

I have a class say `TestEmail` which has a `sendEmail()` method

Now the `sendEmail` method calls an apache commons method which internally call methods from the `javax.mail` package. I want to override one of the internal methods. I am providing the code flow below:

```
TestEmail.sendEmail()->
commons.Email.send()->commons.Email.sendMIMEMessage()->
javax.mail.Transport.send()->javax.mail.Transport(){saveChanges()}-> 
javax.mail.MimeMessage.updateHeaders()->updateMessageID()
```

I want to override the `updateMessageID` method. within my `TestEmail` class. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Not sure it's possible, unless you also override all upper methods to call the newer versions.

Comment: Unless ― of course ― you have acces to their source, so you can change just 2 classes, the one you want to change, and the method _directly_ calling it.

Comment: This is a java internal method. I am looking for a solution without modifying its source code. I am not sure if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387207/can-a-parent-call-child-class-methods

Comment: Well, is the method _calling_ the method you want to override, within your scope?

Comment: This would contradict the *encapsulation principle*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you would just override Email.createMimeMessage(Session) in which ever subclass of Email that you are using.  Then have createMimeMessage return a subclass of javax.mail.MimeMessage that overrides updateMessageID to do what you want. If you just need to remove the userid then there are other ways to do that.  See: [Override Message-ID by configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647529/override-message-id-by-configuration) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be possible by extending three classes: commons.Email, javax.mail.Transport and javax.mail.MimeMessage; and overriding their respective methods to use new behavior of updateMessageID().

Comment: But what if I don't have the source and I don't have any idea what else is done?( `super` won't help, as it would still call the un-overrided version...)